# No module named 'softwareproperties'

Tags: 20.04, python, dpkg, python3, add-apt-repository

I previously manually deleted the system's built-in python2 and python3, and then manually installed them again. When I ran the command sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xxxx, I would get this error.How to solve？

```sh
➜  ~ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'softwareproperties'
➜  ~ python --version 
Python 2.7.18
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.8.11
➜  ~ which pip3
/home/jingmian/.local/bin/pip3
➜  ~ which pip 
/home/jingmian/.local/bin/pip
➜  ~ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
➜  ~ which python 
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~ uname -a                                    
Linux jingmian-X3 5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I continued to execute the following command, but it also indicated a failure.

```sh
➜  ~ sudo apt install --reinstall python3-software-properties
Reading package list... complete
Analyzing the dependency tree for the package
Reading status information... complete
The following software will be installed:
python3-apt software-properties-common
Recommended installation:
python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
python3-apt python3-software-properties software-properties-common
3 software packages were upgraded, 0 software packages were newly installed, 0 software packages were uninstalled, and 392 software packages were not upgraded.
13 packages were not fully installed or uninstalled.
You need to download the 0 B/234 kB archive.
Decompressing will consume 0 B of extra space.
Do you want to proceed? [Y/n] Y
(Reading the database... There are 418,616 files and directories installed on the system.
Prepare to decompress... /python3-apt_2.0.1ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Warning: The old python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returns error status 1
dpkg: Now try using the script that comes with the new package...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
DPKG: processing file/var/cache/apt/archives/python3 - apt_2. 0.1 ubuntu0.20.04.1 _amd64. Deb error (- unpack) :
The new python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returns error status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 34, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Error while cleaning:
The python3-apt package has been installed. The post-installation script subprocess returns error status 1
Prepare to decompress... / software-property-common_0.99.9.12_all.deb...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Warning: The old software-property-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned an error
False state 1
dpkg: Now try using the script that comes with the new package...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
DPKG: processing file/var/cache/apt/archives/software - the properties - common_0. 99.9.12 _all.
Error when deb (--unpack) :
The new software-property-common package pre-removal script subprocess returns error status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 34, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Error while cleaning:
The post-installation script subprocess of the installed software-property-common software package returns an error
State 1
Prepare to decompress... /python3-software-properties_0.99.9.12_all.deb...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Warning: Return of the old python3-software-properties package pre-removal script subprocess
Error status 1
dpkg: Now try using the script that comes with the new package...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
from debpython import files as dpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
DPKG: processing file/var/cache/apt/archives/python3 - software - properties_0. 99.9.12 _all
Error when.deb (--unpack) :
The new python3-software-properties package pre-removal script subprocess returns error status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 34, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: Error while cleaning:
The python3-software-properties package has been installed. The post-installation script subprocess returns an error. Procedure
State 1
An error occurred while processing:
The/var/cache/apt/archives/python3 - apt_2. 0.1 ubuntu0.20.04.1 _amd64. Deb
The/var/cache/apt/archives/software - the properties - common_0. 99.9.12 _all. Deb
The/var/cache/apt/archives/python3 - software - properties_0. 99.9.12 _all. Deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have the correct python3 version?   The *default* version should not be removed/changed, yet you mention removing it then re-installing it; the errors you've shown could be because you didn't re-install the correction version your 20.04 system was built to use.

Comment: I tried to reinstall python3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8, but the problem persisted

Comment: You need to to reinstall the Python version from the Ubuntu respos: Do _not_ install any other version manually or try to replace the system's version from he repo with a manually installed one. This may mess up you system pretty bad up to a not usable state anymore.

Comment: reinstall the Python version from the Ubuntu respos, could you please provide detailed steps for my reference

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS requires this package to be installed `python3-minimal | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2  | focal          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which will upgraded to use `3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8` automatically. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does **not** include `python2` by default  as it was already EOL prior to release of 2020-April (https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)  Key though is the version of python3 in these packages **must** be the default version of python3.

Comment: But my new installation, ubuntu20.04, does include python2.7 by default. Type 'python' into the terminal and it will start, and version 2.7. Right now I can't install anything about pyhon dependencies using apt-get install

Comment: You can look at the manifest of what is included; eg. 20.04.6 Server (arm64) will include packages found here - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.6/release/ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-arm64.manifest and you'll note no python2.7; it was removed late 2019 prior to Python 2.7 EOL.  Your system has been altered.

Comment: Through the URL you sent, I found that python2.7 is not included. Then I need to delete my python2.7 and set python3.8 as the default. Are you trying it